# Select option from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to select an option from an `html select`with C# code, the options of this input are created via AJAX call, after page load my select is something like this:

```
<select id="SelectId" runat="server">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

And on my C# code I have the following code:

```
ListItem li = SelectId.Items.FindByValue("1");

if (li != null)
   li.Selected = true;
else
   Response.Write("mm");
```

But I always get the response.write("mm"), what I'm doing wrong? Maybe is for the ajax call? That when I execute my C# code my select do not have any option?

**EDIT:**

Tested with options created manually and works fine, so the problem is the way of how I create the select options, so how can I solve this? I need to execute my C# code automatically on page load.

**EDIT 2:**

AJAX code:

```
success: function (data) {
   var options = "";
   var myData = JSON.parse(data.d);
   for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
      var id = myData[i].Id;
      options += '<option value ="' + id + '">';
      options += id;
      options += '</option>';
   }
   $('#SelectId').html(options);    
}
```

Comment: Check if this helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4317441/1559611

Comment: Can you share how you create the select options? Since, as you said, that is probably where the problem lies. If you are creating the options client-side then the server side code will not know about them on page load.

Comment: I think you should post more of your code. Are you using an AsynchPostBackTrigger with your Ajax UpdatePanel? This may be of some help: https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers.. check Listing 3 for example.

Comment: @sam2929 Ready, I added the ajax code.

Comment: dynamic controls can be a pain. Quick and dirty just use conventional approach: `Request.Form["SelectId"]`.

Comment: @Crowcoder and where I have to use that code? On my ajax call?

Comment: Apologies, somehow I missed the point of your question. I thought you were wanting the selected value during postback. My bad.

Comment: @MiguelFlores Thanks for adding your ajax code. As I mentioned in my previous comment, if you are configuring the options for your select on the client-side (which you are), then your server side code will not have access to those options on page load. Instead you will have to set the selected item via client-side code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I need to save the selected value for personal reasons, so as I can't do this with C# I use `JavaScript` and `sessionStorage` so my code to solve this issue is the following:

```
function saveSelect() {
   $('#SelectId').change(function () {
      var option = $('#SelectId').val();
      localStorage.SelecteOption = option;
   });
}

function loadSelect() {
   var option = localStorage.SelecteOption;

   if (option != null)
       $('#SelectId').val(option).change();
}
```

And I just call this functions after fill the select.

```
Ajax Call code....

$('#id').html(opciones);
saveSelect();
loadSelect();
```